# Как выводить по 2 строки из файла не рандомно а по порядке?

Tags: php

Как выводить по 2 строки из файла не рандомно, а по порядке, хоть сначала, хоть с конца?

иначе неработает и не выводит по две строки если не ставить рандомно,  а это не совсем хорошо иногда бывает выводит две одинаковые строки

```
    $arr = file("reviews.dat");

shuffle($arr);

$res = array_slice($arr, 0, 2);

foreach ($res as $str) {

    echo $str;

}


$arr = file("reviews.dat");

shuffle($arr);

for($i=0; $i<2; $i++) {

    echo $arr[$i];  
}
```

Comment: Убрать `shuffle()` который перемешивает массив?

Comment: Не дает ничего убирать shuffle()

Comment: Функция [shuffle()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) перемешивает массив, потому и порядок у Вас рандомный, если я верно понял Вашу проблему.

Comment: иначе неработает и не выводит по две строки если не ставить рандомно,  а это не совсем хорошо иногда бывает выводит две одинаковые строки

Comment: *"иначе неработает и не выводит по две строки если не ставить рандомно"* --- это бред сивой кабылы.... Такого быть не может....

Comment: ты просто сам не понимаешь что ты делаешь - это единственная причина почему что-то иногда не работает без shuffle ......... а выводить по две строки банально можно через for, где счётчик инкрементируется не на 1, а на 2

Comment: Может вы контент файла посмотрите сами и нам покажите? И ожидаемый вывод еще? А то не ясно, вам надо разбить на пары, или просто вытащить две строки с начала, две с конца.

Answer (score 4):

Скорее всего должно быть так:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i += 2) { // $i += 2 - для перехода по двум элементом в цикле
    echo $arr[$i];
    echo ' ';
    echo array_key_exists($i + 1, $arr) ? $arr[$i + 1] : '';
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Вторая строка включает в себя проверку потому, что число элементов может быть нечётным

---

Для сильно обеспокоенных людей - такой вывод echo я сделал специально, чтобы было понятно ТС'у

Comment: Не работает в таком виде

Comment: Всё вполне себе работает. [пруф](https://onlinephp.io/c/e23fb) Просто у тебя видимо ещё куча всякого непонятного написано, из-за чего получается не то, что нужно

Answer (score 0):

Если вместо файла мы разобьем строку в массив

```
$data = "a,b,c,d,e,f";
$arr = explode(',', $data);
```

То следующий код получит первые два элемента, последние два элемента, и исходный массив разбитый на пары последовательных строк:

```
$first = array_slice($arr, 0, 2);
$last = array_slice($arr, -2, 2);
$pairs = array_chunk($arr, 2);
```

Можно написать `[$first, $second] = array_slice($arr, 0, 2)` и получите в каждой переменной первую и вторую строку файла соответственно.

Comment: Он просто косноязычный. Ему нужно не "первые две", а *по две.* То есть не всегда показывать первые две, а при каждом обращении к файлу показывать следующие. Ну то есть всегда показывать разные. И с этой точки зрения показывать рандомные - то, как у него сделано сейчас - это как раз оптимальное решение.